# gmap shows one fourth after one  load in jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to show gmap on the basis of longitude and latitude which are available in `repeater control data source` .here is my code

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey&sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('.mapicon').click(function (e) {              
            init($(this).next('.hdnLatitude').val(), $(this).nextAll('.hdnLongitude').val(), $(this).nextAll('.hdnInfoWindow').val());
            $("#popup_container").dialog({ modal: true }, { border: 10 }, { width: 513 }, { height: 450 });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the init method which load gmap in

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function init(hdnLatitude, hdnLongitude, hdnInfoWindow) {
            //            alert(hdnLatitude);
            //            alert(hdnLongitude);

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(hdnLatitude, hdnLongitude),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            var image = 'images/map-icon.gif';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(hdnLatitude, hdnLongitude),
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(hdnInfoWindow);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });

        }
    </script>
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div id="popup_container" style="display: none;">
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

the problem is when first time click on `mapicon` then gmap appears correctly but after that in every call popup opens but map appear one fourth and marker is not appearing correctly.

**Edited**

Unfotunately i am not getting a single answer or may be possible that my question is not clear to SO users.

I have made a test page where you can check that whats the exact problem.

on first click its shows perfect map but when you close popup once and again click on `gmap` then popup opens but `gmap` shows one fourth.

[this is link of test page](http://e-hotelspro.com/gmap.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally problem resolved by making some changes or adjustment in dialog open method

initially  use the  `$("#popup_container").dialog({ autoOpen: false });` instead of

`style=display:none`  for not showing popup on page load .

second change i made open the popup using this call to open method

```
$('#popup_container').dialog('open');
```

and after that i call the `init()` method

and problem is solved .

Here is final `document.ready` method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function () {
            $("#popup_container").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
            $('#gmap').click(function () {
                $('#popup_container').dialog('open');
                $("#popup_container").dialog({ modal: true }, { border: 10 }, { width: 500 }, { height: 340 });
                init();
            });
        });
    </script>
```